# Azure pipeline For Multiple Projects

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have a solution with an web api project and a blazor webassembly project. If I create a pipeline to create an artifact for release, it all works great untill I visit the domain where I can only visit my blazor webassembly project. How am I able to access the api?

azure pipeline:

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

# trigger:
# - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'BackEndRelease'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Use .NET 6.0
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '6.0.x'
    
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

I use the artifact to create a release pipeline.
I even created my own build configuration (BackEndRelease) where I unchecked the blazor project, but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to specify the API project in Solution file.

You can add msbuild argument in the VSBuild task.

Here are the steps:

1.Check the target Project name in Solution file.

For example:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "test", "test\test.csproj", "{497AD76F-222C-4BEB-BDCB-401B0E80B5CE}"
```

2.Add the target argument in VSbuild. `/t:test`

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site" /t:test'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```